# Java SimpleDateFormat.parse throws : Unparseable date: "2015-10-06T08:00:00+00:00" (at offset 10)

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone, date-parsing

Hello i have the following string with datetime:

```
public static String nextOccurenceString = "2015-10-06T08:00:00+00:00";
```

And i want to parse and format string into the following format by following pattern:

```
public static String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

But when i try to call method which should parse the date string into date object i always get exception:

```
Unparseable date: "2015-10-06T08:00:00+00:00" (at offset 10)
```

Method is following:

```
public static void convertStringToDate(String dateString) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf;
                sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
                Date test = sdf.parse(nextOccurenceString);
                Logger.d(test.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.e(e.getMessage());
            }

    }
```

And I'm using the standard formatting and parsing class:

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
```

How can i solve it please? Should replace something in  **nextOccurenceString** or can i work with string in format like:
**"2015-10-06T08:00:00+00:00"** ?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Well, the format indeed doesn't match, right?

Comment: Almost every single case of "SimpleDateFormat.parse throws an exception" is due to not paying enough attention to whether the format string matches the actual data you've got. Not only is your format string missing the UTC offset part, it also doesn't have a T in it.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is wrong. It must be:

```
public static String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
```

For more information read the javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

The correct pattern for your string is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) and not `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`